# Is this recursion is posible?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain to me how this piece of recursive code is working? Because there is only one if statement which checks if variable x is equal to zero and returns true if the value is equal to zero.
And the other part is just upon calling each other.

```
def is_even(x):
  if x == 0:
    return True
  else:
    return is_odd(x-1)

def is_odd(x):
  return not is_even(x)

print(is_odd(17))  # outputs true
print(is_even(23))  # outputs false
```

Comment: Check it in e.g. http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pair of [*mutually recursive* functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) makes use of three facts:

1. 0 is even
2. `x` is even if `x - 1` is odd.
3. `x` is odd if `x - 1` is even.

1 is odd because 1 - 1 == 0 is even.

2 is even because 2 - 1 == 1 is odd.

And so on.

This is not an *efficient* way to determine if an arbitrary value `n` is even or odd, but it is a logically *correct* way. (Assuming the argument is always a *natural* number, anyway. Passing a negative integer as an argument to either results in infinite recursion, as the base case will never be reached.)

Comment: The second function is not recursive at all. It just calls the negation of a recursive function, but only once.

Comment: @csabinho I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Neither function is recursive on its own, but the pair together is implemented using [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion). Neither definition is complete without the definition of the other. (Though in the special case of `x == 0`, `is_even` can be *evaluated* without calling `is_odd`.)

Comment: Seems to be an example of [mutual recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutual-recursion-example-hofstadter-female-male-sequences/)

Comment: @chepner--take it easy.  I didn't see your reply to casbinho until after I had posted my reply (i.e. times close together).

Answer (score 0):

I want to give a simpler answer to follow along with. Think about the stack trace. I'll abbreviate `is_even` and `is_odd` as IE and IO respectively.

```
IO(17)
NOT[IE(17)]
NOT[IO(16)]
NOT[NOT[IE(16)] = IE[16]
IO(15)
...
```

This is basically checking if alternating descending numbers starting from the input value are even and odd all the way down to 0. Note that if we start with a true statement (like `IO(17)`) then every line contains a true statement - if we started with a false statement, every line ends up with a false statement. Following the pattern we see here, we see that the final state can therefore end up as

```
IE(1) -> IO(0) -> NOT[IE(0)] = NOT[True] = False # as expected!
```

OR

```
IO(1) -> NOT[IE[1]] = NOT[IO[0]] = NOT[NOT[IE(0)] = NOT[NOT[True]] = True # likewise!
```